# I'm looping through a vector and trying to use each element as a dataframe column name. How do I get each element to be read after the $ in df3$x?

Tags: r, time-series

Here is my code:

```
    for (x in col_names){
    time_series <- ts(df3$x, frequency=1, start = df3$index[1])
}
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
    Error in ts(df3$x, frequency = 1, start = df3$index[1]): 'ts' object must have one or more observations
Traceback:

1. ts(df3$x, frequency = 1, start = df3$index[1])
2. stop("'ts' object must have one or more observations")
```

I believe this is because R cannot read the `df3$x`. How do I loop through a vector and use an element of that vector as a column name of my dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be with `[[`

```
for (x in col_names){
    time_series <- ts(df3[[x]], frequency=1, start = df3$index[1])
}
```

assuming that `col_names` is vector of specific column names

---

In the OP's code, `time_series` object created will get updated in each iteration.  Instead, would be better to return in a `list`

```
time_series_list <- vector('list' length(col_names))
names(time_series_list) <- col_names
for (x in col_names){
    time_series_list[[x]] <- ts(df3[[x]], frequency=1, start = df3$index[1])
}
```